# Другой компонент WebBrowsera

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Ищу компонент веб браузера который подойдёт под .net 2.0. Максимум .net 3.0.  Awesomium отпадает сразу т.к. Он работает стабильно только на 4.5.х. На платформах ниже он ругается, что не может загрузить сборку. Не использую стандартный т.к. очень кривая реализация JS. И не хочется чтобы пользователю назойливо сообщало об ошибках в скриптах. Может кто знает другие варианты или знает как исправить ошибку с Awesomium. Awesomium уже шёл вместе с VS2015

Answer (score 1):

> Awesomium отпадает сразу т.к. Он работает стабильно только на 4.5.х. На платформах ниже он ругается, что не может загрузить сборку.

Может он и входит в .NET 4.5+. Но он доступен и как отдельная библиотека, тогда никаких проблем с загрузкой сборок не будет, и юзать его можно будет и под .NET 4.0
Вот здесь есть пример с ним, и еще пара движков, правда, не бог весть каких интересных:
[http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/825526/Csharp-WebBrowser-vs-Gecko-vs-Awesomium-vs-OpenWeb](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/825526/Csharp-WebBrowser-vs-Gecko-vs-Awesomium-vs-OpenWeb)
Еще есть CefSharp. Можно загрузить и подключить через NuGet.

И такой вопрос - а для чего вам вообще браузерный движок?